# How to reference compatibility mode in Internet Explorer via code?

Tags: html, powershell, internet-explorer, cmd

I have a project where we are automatically logging in, etc. to a website (FYI, it's hosted on a local network and only access from that. Not a public website on the Internet) to monitor info and parameters that the website displays. The issue is the login window can not be accessed in when I have the website set to "compatibility mode" in Internet Explorer. However, the rest of the website only works properly if I run in compatibility mode.

Either I need a script to set compatibility mode totally on or off for that website that I can run along with the login commands or else a way to specify a total URL that would not run in compatibility mode while the rest of the site does.

I'm using WinAutomation to handle running Command Prompt, PowerShell, etc. commands so I have a fairly wide range of options.

I'd really like to build a Windows command that would take care of handling this. I've searched high and low only to come up with some register and GOP options that don't quite do the trick.

Comment: force-ie-11-compatibility-mode-for-certain-sites-within-domain http://serverfault.com/questions/627529/force-ie-11-compatibility-mode-for-certain-sites-within-domain

Comment: Thanks for he answer, I did some more work on this and I haven't found a solution yet. Issue is my URL http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/login* is the only URL that can NOT run in compatibility mode. The rest of the website of http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/* must run in compatibility mode. How can I give priority to on URL and have the rest run in compatibility mode?

Comment: could the login be login.blah.com and everything else be blah.com?  Then you could I assume apply two different rules with the domain trick

Comment: I have no access to change the web server. Only thing would be to set something up locally on the computer that would do that and then yes, it would fix the issue. I don't have any experience with something like that outside of across the internet...

Comment: @patrick What about an option that would change on the fly without needing to restart IE. The GOP options etc, only become active after closing IE and then opening again. If you need to only load a login page outside of compatibility mode that does not work.

Comment: Maybe look into DOCTYPE declarations.  If its on your local network adding the right docType declaration to the login.aspx (or whatever it is) might fix it.